# Using L'Hopital's Rule to show limit is 0?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to show for any non-negative integer $n$, $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0+} \frac{e^{-{1 /x}}}{x^n}=0$.  For $n=0$ this follows directly since $1/x \rightarrow +\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0+$.  For $n>0$, I notice the limit has indeterminate form $0/0$ but applying L'Hopital's Rule directly gives $ \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0+} \frac{e^{-{1 /x}}}{nx^{n+1}}$, which only seems to complicate the problem.  Also, it seems that repeatedly applying the rule would just increase the exponent of $x$ on the denominator.  Why doesn't L'Hopitals Rule not work directly in this problem, and how could it be used, if at all, to evaluate the limit?  Alternatively, is there another method to evaluate it?

Comment: @selfawareuser. L'Hospital's Rule is in general correct. There are proofs to support that.  It is important to the user to know how to use it. That's what matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this limit can be done through a simple substitution. As indicated we assume $x\to0^+$ for your limit. Setting $x=1/t$, the limit becomes $\lim \limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{t^n}{e^t}$. After applying L'Hospital's Rule sufficient amount of times (it's an infinity over infinity situation), your polynomial numerator gets "exhausted" whereas the e-power in the denom stays "as is". And thus the limit goes to zero!

Answer (score 0):

Note that you want $x\to0^+$. Rewrite the expression as $$ \exp\left(-\frac1x-n\log x\right)=\exp\left(-\frac{1+nx\log x}{x}\right).$$ Now L'Hôpital will show that the numerator of the exponent goes to $1$, and thus the whole expression will go to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

No *L'Hospital's rule* required here: setting $u=\dfrac1x$, it comes down to showing $\;\displaystyle\lim_{u\to +\infty}\dfrac{u^n}{\mathrm e^u}=0 $, which is a result from high school.

Comment: I agree that this is a standard limit. But how do you prove this limit as a result....from High School?

Comment: In high school, you prove $\dfrac{\log^nt}{t}\to 0$ as $t\to+\infty$  by showing $\log t<2n\,t^{1/2n}$ . From which you deduce at once the limit for the exponential.

Comment: Yes, that derivation makes certainly sense. I am just not so sure about the High School part. But then, I never went to High School here:)

Comment: Here *where*? $ $

Comment: I mean to say, I never went to a US High School. I do know they cover L'Hospital's rule for several cases (like 0/0 and infty/infty), hence my approach in the answer I posted. Your answer is certainly very clean and worth noting, but I have not seen that in a High School context. On the other hand, when I was in school during my teenage years, I had no clue what math I was doing ...:)

Comment: I didn't either, I'm in Europe. And they certainly should not learn L'Hospital's rule, which can be dangerous to apply, because most people don't check the conditions that have to be satisfied. Furthermore, when it works, Taylor at order $1$ works as well, and it's far less dangerous.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45783/discussion-between-imranfat-and-bernard).